# JavaScript build options/tools

Tags: javascript, redirect, build, compression, http-status-code-301

These days I find myself shifting out more and more work to the client side and hence my JS files tend to get bigger and bigger. I have come to the point where most HTML pages have half a dozen or more JS imports in the header and I realised that this is hurting loading times.

I have recently discovered this [script](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Supercharged_Javascript) which lets you download several JS files with one HTTP request. It is written in PHP and being a Django fan I'm planning to rewrite it in Python. I'm planning to use a HTTP redirect to the pre-minified and concatenated file and was wondering what the cost of a 301 would be. Please let me know if that is a stupid idea.

On the other hand, am little worried about introducing scripting logic into the serving of static files and I was wondering if there is a viable build alternative like, say, an ant task that concatenates and minifies JS files and replaces multiple JS downloads in a HTML header with one big one, like the script does.

Answer (score 4):

For PHP I certainly favour doing it dynamically just because if you introduce a build step you're losing one of the main benefits of using PHP. In fact, at the risk of self-promotion I've written [Supercharging Javascript in PHP](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-javascript.html) about this very issue.

Of course other technologies may vary.

Again it is PHP but it's not just a lump of code for you to use (although you can jump straight to [Part 6](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-javascript-part-6.html) if you just want some fully working code) and may have value to you in terms of identifying the issues and doing things the right way and why you do them that way.

I favour having bundles of Javascript files (maybe only one for the entire application) and then each page simply activates the behaviour it needs through standard means but all the code bodies are in the larger cached and minified JS file. It works out fastest this way and is a good way to go.

If you do want it as part of a build process, which is a reasonable solution if you have a build process anyway, then I suggest you minify your code. There are lots of tools to do this. Have a look at [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).

If you do a static combine of JS files, the other stuff mentioned above such as gzipping and associated issues is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

YUI compressor is a good choice. If you want to learn how to set up an Ant-based build process, have a look at this Tutorial: http://www.javascriptr.com/2009/07/21/setting-up-a-javascript-build-process/

As a Ruby-based alternative, I would recommend [Sprockets](http://www.getsprockets.com/)